# Get SlideJS to work fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've failed at trying to get SlideJS to work fullscreen... It seems to have whitespace around it no matter what I do and it never fits.

I need the FULL background to be like SlideJS's slider, so that the background slides every 5 seconds to the next page/slide (which is a block color with some text such as "Welcome to my site." then on the next slide, with a different block background color it may say "My name is blah and I blah blah." and a different  icon on each slide).

When using a plugin such as Superslides, it seems to set EVERY single images that I put in each slide container as the background image, I only want a block color for the background which changes each slide; not an image as the background.

So, I need to get a full-page/screen sliding background which lets you have images inside the slides (unlike Superslides which doesn't as it sets them to "position: absolute; ...").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into a similar situation.

This is what I did to fix it.

Look for this function in the source (around line 231) and change the width and height variables to $(window).width(); and .height();
:

```
Plugin.prototype.update = function() {
  var $element, height, width;
  $element = $(this.element);
  this.data = $.data(this);
  $(".slidesjs-control", $element).children(":not(:eq(" + this.data.current + "))").css({
    display: "none",
    left: 0,
    zIndex: 0
  });
  width = $(window).width();
  height = $(window).height();
  return $(".slidesjs-control, .slidesjs-container", $element).css({
    width: width,
    height: height
  });
};
```