# Having trouble using rhino slider with a full page image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a rhino slider to my website which will fade in and out of multiple images at full screen size. The rhinoslider I am using is: [Rhinoslider](http://www.rhinoslider.com/demo-download/?settings=fade%7C3000%7C1000%7Cswing%7Cfalse%7Cfalse%7Cfalse%7Cfalse%7Cfalse%7Ctrue%7Ctrue%7Cfalse%7Ctrue%7C650%7C250%7C0.7%7C100%7C150%7C5,3%7Cnever%7Cnever%7Cafter%7Cnever%7CtoLeft%7CtoRight%7Cprev%7Cnext%7Cplay%7Cpause%7Cposition,top,right,bottom,left,margin-top,margin-right,margin-bottom,margin-left,width,height) I can get this so the slider works but in doing so it pushes the other divisions underneath the slider further down the page where they shouldn't be.

The code:

HTML:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/rhinoslider-1.05.css" type="text/css"  />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/rhinoslider-1.05.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mousewheel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#slider').rhinoslider({
                    effect: 'fade',
                    controlsMousewheel: false,
                    controlsKeyboard: false,
                    controlsPrevNext: false,
                    controlsPlayPause: false,
                    autoPlay: true,
                    pauseOnHover: false,
                    showBullets: 'never',
                    showControls: 'never'
                });
            });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="CVHeader">
            <ul id="slider">
                <li><img src="images/CVHeader.jpg"/></li>
                    <li><img src="images/hmb-header-image.jpg"/></li>
                </ul> 
        </div>

 <div id="expertisediv">

        <div class="largeshape1">

            <img src="images/largeshape1.jpg"/>

        </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

main CSS:

```
.CVHeader {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    }

    #slider li { 
    list-style:none;
    }

    #slider{ 
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    }

#expertisediv {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    padding-bottom:8%;
    float:left;
    }

    .largeshape1 {
    width: 19.3%;
    height:auto;
    min-height: 120px;
    max-height:auto;
    padding-top:4.5%;
    float:left;
    }
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Without seeing your actual content/page and knowing what "divisions" are being pushed down it's a little difficult to help further. I am assuming your "expertisediv" is being pushed down? Are you wanting that inside the slider content? or what can you show a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: Immediately after the the slider. Everything that is below it is being pushed down by at least half a page. Is there anything else I can do to help explain more?

Comment: Well can you include the CSS for the items being pushed down? You have only supplied the slider related styles.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick Fiddle of  your code above, obviously using some different images.

I can only assume either your slider or other code somewhere in your page is breaking the site, because you can see here, the lower DIV is not being pushed down that far, just the padding % that is specified in your CSS.

```
padding-top:4.5%;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1g8gha62/

Maybe try to edit that padding value to a specific pixel value instead of percent? just a thought.

Comment: Thanks, Although you haven't used the rhinoslider? That is just a basic image header...it is the slider that is causing the problem....

Comment: If you are able to share a URL to the issue, i could probably tell you in a hot minute what the issue is. =)

Comment: It's not live yet, so you would need the source files etc...? Is there anyway of sharing that...

Comment: Is this an HTML site? if so, you can share the files with me if you like. I am not sure if we can provide email on here or if that is frowned upon, but here it is: mikeisrain@gmail.com

Comment: Ok, I will email across Michael. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yeah I thought so...so is there a solution then??

Comment: So i looked at the entire site files, and its coming down to the Rhinoslider js that is making a hot mess of everything. I don't believe the slider is a very good choice, (my opinion) even since it it not responsive whatsoever. I would highly recommend another solution that offers this functionality you seek, something even like  http://www.slidesjs.com/ which I have used many times before.

Comment: You can even set it fullscreen using a similar approach as they have on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326330/get-slidejs-to-work-fullscreen

Comment: Ok thanks Michael  I will have another look tomorrow at a different slider. Isit that a fade slider?

Comment: It does offer multiple transitions, and fade is one. =)  Good luck my friend.